# gspread - Using "find" function for input values

Tags: python, python-3.x, gspread

I'm writing a Python program using gspread and was wondering if there's any easy way to use the "find" function to search by input values instead of plain values.

For example, I'm trying to locate `=HYPERLINK("https://stackoverflow.com","Stack Overflow")` instead of just `Stack Overflow`. Just want to make sure there's nothing I'm missing before I attempt to rewrite the function.

Thanks! :)

Comment: It's a good point. But I'm afraid at the moment (gspread v3.0.0) the only way to accomplish this is by subclassing `Worksheet` and overriding `Worksheet._finder` so when it calls `values_get` it passes `params={'valueRenderOption': 'FORMULA'}`. You can take a look at the `Worksheet.cell` definition to get an example of such call.
_Note to the future readers_: please check the current version of gspread as there could be a much simpler way to do this in upcoming releases.

Comment: Also, please consider adding this as a feature request to https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues

Comment: Thanks so much, @Burnash! And thanks for gspread! :)